# How to call js script file in asp.net core Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

How to call js script file (app.js) in the section of `@code`

```
<script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/app.js">
function indexSlider(){
 alert(1);
}
```

```
@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!firstRender)
        {
            return;
        }

        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("indexSlider");

    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you want to call js file?If you just want to load the app.js like using third-party js,you could set it to _Host.cshtml.If you want to invoke the method in app.js,you could follow the docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-of-ijsruntime

Comment: can you specify more your problem its unclear , what is your error, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call JavaScript function (from external library) with Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406662/call-javascript-function-from-external-library-with-blazor)

Answer (score 1):

Example JS code timer

```
var clock;
var date;
function startTime(element) {
    let timeString = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true, minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'});
    let dateString = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { dateStyle: 'full'});
    element.innerHTML = dateString + " - " + timeString;
    clock = setTimeout(startTime.bind(null, element), 1000);
}
function stopTime() {
    clearTimeout(clock);
}
```

In your `wwwroot` folder find `index.html`

```
<script src='js/yourJS.js'></script>
```

In your razor component or page

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntimeService

<div @ref='timeElement'></div>

@code
{
ElementReference timeElement;
     protected overried async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
        await jsRuntimeService.InvokeVoidAsync("startTime", timeElement);
        await jsRuntimeService.InvokeVoidAsync("Alertfunction");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@code{
IJSObjectReference module;
module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import","~/js/app.js");
await module.InvokeVoidAsync("indexSlider", null);}
```

this is how you can do it and in your js file define a function like this.

```
export function indexSlider() 
{ //do something};
```