# Call JavaScript function (from external library) with Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I try to call a JS function. The JS script is provided by a third party.

In simple HTML/JS, I can write:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="myscriptA.js"></script>
        <script src="myscriptB.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo"></div>
        <div id="bar"></div>
        <script>
            var viewer = new foo.Viewer('foo', /*other params*/);
            viewer.function1().then(() => { /*ommited code*/ }).catch((error) => { console.log(error)});
            document.getElementById('bar').addEventListener('click', event => {
                var b1 = new B('bar', /*params*/)});
                var b2 = new B('foo');
            viewer.addB(b1, b2, { click: function(e) { viewer.function2() } });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to do the same thing with Blazor. For the moment, I can reach the `myscriptA.js` file with my component:

`Page3.razor`

```
@page "/Page3"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@code {
    var scriptA = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/myscriptA.js");
    var foo = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("new foo.Viewer", scriptA);
    // I have try:
    var foo = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("new foo.Viewer", "foo", @*other params*@);
    var foo = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("foo.Viewer", "foo", @*other params*@);
    var foo = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("Viewer", "foo", @*other params*@);
    var foo = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("new Viewer", "foo", @*other params*@);
}
```

For each C# foo variable in my component, my browser's console shows:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'new foo.Viewer' ('new foo' was undefined).
      Error: Could not find 'new foo.Viewer' ('new foo' was undefined).
          at https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1287
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at e.findFunction (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1247)
          at b (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2989)
          at https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3935
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3908)
          at Object.w [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:64232)
          at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost:5001/_framework/dotnet.5.0.4.js:1:190800)
          at do_icall (<anonymous>:wasm-function[10596]:0x194e4e)
```

## Updates

### May 8th, 2021: index.html

As written in the comment ([Call JavaScript function (from external library) with Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406662/call-javascript-function-from-external-library-with-blazor/67407434#67407434)), I want to inject `myscriptA.js` and `myscriptB.js` only in `Page3.razor` file and not in another files (`Page1`, `Page2`, `Page4`, ...).

### May 11th, 2021: js file

As *.css files for Blazor components, I tried to add a *.js file with the same name as my page:

- `Project.csproj`

  - `Pages` folder

    - `Page1.razor`
    - `Page2.razor`
    - `Page2.razor.css` <-- seen in a `Shared\NavMenu.razor`
    - `Page3.razor`
    - `Page3.razor.js`

> I've the same error

Answer (score 11):

You were close!! To load a JS file only where required (e.g., a specific page), you need to implement the `IJSObjectReference` interface and utilize the JavaScript module isolation properly.

Razor page:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<h1>My Page</h1>

@code{
private IJSObjectReference MyJsModule { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        try
        {
            // Load the JS Helpers Module
            MyJsModule = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/MyScript.js");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Failed to load JS module. Error: {ex}");
        }
    }
}

private async void AddViewer()
{
    try
    {
        await MyJsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("AddViewer", "foo");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError($"Failed to execute JS function. Error: {ex}");
    }
}
```

MyScript.js file:

```js
import "./myScriptWithUsefulCodes.min.js";

export function AddViewer(id) {
    var viewer = new foo.Viewer(id, /*other params*/);
    /* ...Your code... */
}
```

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules

Comment: I'm getting `Failed to fetch dynamically imported module` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the `import "myscript.js"` file properly. Check your folder structure and pathing.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just load the JavaScript file in your Blazor Page, the same way as the default Blazor example loads the `.json` file?

And then 'execute' the contents from that string as JavaScript using the IJSRuntime ?