# How to Correctly Inject JS into Blazor?

Tags: javascript, css, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I’m building a Blazor WASM website and I had a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379202/why-cant-i-load-any-js-after-my-blazor-server-js).

I used the solution, but the problem is that the JS library I’m using is `tilt.js`, which when initialized, captures all of the objects it’s going to have the effect on. The page I need it on is not the main one, so when you click to that page there is no effect. But as soon as you reload the page, boom the page works like a charm!

EDIT: Here is the Code to Add the JS to the mainlayout.razor file

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/vanilla-tilt.js");
    }
}
```

Then I have these tags to the html elements I want to be move

```
data-tilt data-tilt-max="15" data-tilt-speed="400" data-tilt-glare data-tilt-scale="1.15" data-tilt-max-glare="0.5"
```

But the page only does the parallax when you reload the page it is supposed to be on! Thus parallax is then broken.

Comment: Could you please post a minimum example of your code demonstrating the problem. I dont feel like writing a sample app just to explore this. I suspect you just need to call the enable code on first render of your component / page. This is why it works on refresh. The Tilt repo shows how to enable and disable the effect on click.

Comment: Where are you seeing enable and disable?

Comment: I edited the above post to show more info!

Comment: Add StateHasChanged() after JSRuntime.InvokeAsync.  That may fix it for you.

Comment: That did not work, any other ideas?

Comment: @3GamersStudios, I answered a very similar question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406662/call-javascript-function-from-external-library-with-blazor/67536500#67536500. Basically, you have to wrap the library in a JS module to access it with C# via Interop.

Comment: You need to call a method to _activate_ the library.